# Question about Reverse Linked List (leetcode 206)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I know my code is completely wrong, but I do not know where I did wrong,

can anyone point out and explain what I did wrong?

```
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return head;
    }
    
    ListNode prev = null;
    ListNode current = head;
    ListNode nextNode = head.next;
    
    while (nextNode != null) {
        prev = current;
        current = nextNode;
        current.next = prev;
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
        System.out.println(nextNode.val);
    }
    
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Look at the order in which you execute `current.next = prev;` and `nextNode = nextNode.next;` - `current` and `nextNode` refer to the same node before these two lines, so what do you think happens when you execute them

Comment: Is this Java? If so, you might want to add the tag to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes:

1. head.next = null; // to make the end of the list as null
2. current.next = prev; // current is the reference to the node so changes to it will change node with reference nextNode also

   ```
   public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return head;
        }

        ListNode prev = null;
        ListNode current = head;
        ListNode nextNode = head.next;
        head.next = null;   // to make the end of the list as null

        while (nextNode != null) {
            prev = current;
            current = nextNode;
            nextNode = nextNode.next;   // first get next node, before ...
            current.next = prev;        // ... overwriting it here
            // System.out.println(nextNode.val);
        }

        return current;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative Solution

We can just say `while head != null` and then reverse it using a `prev` Node, finally we would return the `prev`. It'd be easier:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        ListNode prev = null;
        ListNode nextNode;

        while (head != null) {
            nextNode = head.next;
            head.next = prev;
            prev = head;
            head = nextNode;
        }

        return prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: While your code is more elegant, presenting entirely new code does not help someone learn why his code does not work. The answer by @yash-shah is more helpful as it points our where to change the his code.